# OpenGL Lightning

Tags: c++, opengl

After enabling lighting in OpenGL, color in lines and polygons are no longer rendering. (Created color from `glColor3f()` )

This is code:

```
        glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, GL_TRUE);
        GLfloat light1_position[] = { 5000, 2000, 1000,1 };
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light1_position);
        GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 1,1,1,1 };
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have these set ? `glEnable ( GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH);`

Comment: If you're new to OpenGL, please don't start with the old non-shader OpenGL. It will just teach you bad practice.

Comment: I you understand, but on my language is not available books by OpenGL (on new version). And my English is bad :(

Answer (score 6):

You must enable these things before using them :

```
glEnable ( GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); 
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH);
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use `GL_SMOOTH`, you can also use `GL_FLAT`.